# How to structure and normalize data for searchability with multiple data values per field?

Tags: database-design, database-schema

I'm trying to work out database structure for an archiving purpose. The application seeks to store data for the main purposes of ease and speed of searchability and also future scalability.

For example a db with n-main types of data, say, ARTICLE (primary content of db), Journal, Author etc each of which will have its own table and ID. But each ARTICLE may have more than 1 author and it may have been published in more than 1 journal. Then there are also tags relating to content information associated with each ARTICLE.

Database needs to be searchable by individual tags (which can also be hierarchical, eg. Wing Design > Swept Wing), 'journals', 'authors', etc and none of these may have a limit to how many are associated with each 'ARTICLE'.

Is normalization possible or even desirable in this case? Is pipeline/space separated data sufficient? What is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance! :)

Edit: To add a few clarifications: I'm using MySQL for this application. Also all the n-main type data apart from article (ie. 'author', 'journal', 'tagset1', 'tagset2'... 'tagset-n' etc are at the same level of data hierarchy and searchability needs)

Comment: You did not mention your db engine. It may have an impact on the answer. SQL Server for instance, has full text indexing capabilities that might be better than normalization in your case.

Comment: Currently I've been using MySQL, and I would like to get a way to do this there. Thanks for the info though, I might be willing to switch if I can't find a better option.

Answer (score 0):

> Is normalization possible or even desirable in this case?

Of course. I'd expect 5NF to be easily possible, and to perform well, too. Normalization depends on certain kinds of dependencies among attributes, not on subject area, so you'd normalize these tables just like you'd normalize the tables for cereal grains, car manufacturers, legal case management, or recipes.

Do the authors have the final decision on what the title is, or do the journals? If the authors, then each article has only one title. If the journals, then each article can have a lot of different titles, and your data entry job gets much harder.

Comment: The final decision of the title is in the authors' hands, so that's do-able. But my doubt with normalization is mainly on how well it will handle the tagging system which makes the searchable datatypes a much larger number than the arbitary three used in the example. Particularly, the Wing Design example: would that part of attached data be normalizable without creating too many tables? (Keeping in mind that there could be any number, realistically anything around 5 to 30 tags attached to each Article and that the tags themselves are also data in the same way author & journal are data)

Comment: @Ficodet: I never worry about the number of tables when I'm normalizing tables. The resulting tables are smaller, narrower, and simpler, usually with tighter constraints.  So they're actually easier to work with. There really can't be "any number" of tags, and there really can't be "any number" of tags in a hierarchy. Categorizing all known life in the universe requires only seven tags. (Kingdom, phylum, class, order, family, genus, species.)  I also don't worry about the number of rows. Indexes and partitions take most of the sting out of big tables.